# Sending request with guzzle with raw data

Tags: php, guzzle

I want to send a request with guzzle that looks like this.

[Post man request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVrlV.png)

Thing is, I always get

> Uncaught exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException' with message 'Client error: `POST http://localhost:8080/project/user/login` resulted in a `400 Bad Request`

Here is the part of the code that creates and sends the request:

```
if (isset ($_REQUEST['username']) && isset($_REQUEST['password'])){
require '../php/vendor/autoload.php';

$myClient = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

$request = $myClient->post("http://localhost:8080/project/user/login");
$request->setBody($_REQUEST['username']. ',' . $_REQUEST['password']);
$feed_response = $request->send();
```

I've read most of the guzzle's manual, but it got me nowhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Guzzle are you using. Use the latest version. In the latest version of Guzzle, a http POST request is sent as:

```
$client->request('POST', '/post', [
    'form_params' => [
        'foo' => 'bar',
        'baz' => ['hi', 'there!']
    ]
]);
```

See this link: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html?#form-params

Comment: Version was the issue then ,thanks a lot for your time :)