# Guzzle Post Request with Query Params and Body

Tags: php, guzzle

I want to use guzzle to send a POST request to a WebService. This Request MUST send 2 parameters on the query string and a body with form_params.

Example: http://localhost:5000/api/V1/Clients/AddClient?sitecode=PT&username=test

And then add a body with form_params to this request.

I'm trying with this code:

```
$Client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([ //Instantiate the guzzle client
  'headers' => [
      'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    ]
]);

$response = $Client->post("http://localhost:5000/api/V1/Clients/AddCustomer", [
  'headers' => [
       'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token
   ],
  'query' => [
      'sitecode' => "PT",
      'username' => "Test",
   ],
  'form_params' => [
      'Client' => json_encode($ClientRegister),
   ]
]);
```

All of this in PostMan works:

[image: Postman Request Image]

The code returns a 500 internal server error. Is expected to get a 200 OK.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: You may want to share what error you get and what is the expected result.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte edited. Sorry

Comment: Error 500 is internal server error. Look at the error_log for more information

Comment: Try this instead https://stackoverflow.com/a/41734133

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but it may as well have an answer; there are a few things wrong with your sample code which do not match your "working" PostMan example:

1. Do not assume "PT" is the same as "pt", or "Test" the same as "test".  It may be fine in your code, but for the sake of clarity, you should be consistent anyway.
2. You introduce a new variable "Client" in your "form_params" which is not in the "working" version.  I think you meant `'form_params' => json_encode($ClientRegister)`
3. Your "working" example is sending "raw" JSON, not using a form at all.  Which leads me to believe you should not be using `form_parms` in the first place because these will be sent as `x-www-form-urlencoded`, not JSON.

Working example, assuming your "working" PostMan is correct:

```
$ClientRegister = [
    'CustomerType' => 1,
    'Etc' => 999,
];

$Client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([ //Instantiate the guzzle client
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    ]
]);

$response = $Client->post($url, [
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
    ],
    'query' => [
        'sitecode' => "pt",
        'username' => "test",
    ],
    'body' => json_encode($ClientRegister)
]);

echo $response->getBody()->getContents();
```

I think the confusion here is between "body" and "form_params", it only makes sense to use one of these, and in your case, to send raw JSON, you should be using "body".